# Display Current Month Birthdays Using Events Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part

I have created an Events List in SharePoint Online for employee birthdays and anniversaries. I am using Power Automate to pull the Birthday and Hire Date for employees in the current month and creating an all day event for each employee's birthday and anniversary in the current month. This works great, however, I'm finding it difficult to display the current month's birthdays/anniversaries on our home site.

It appears that because this list is an Events List (which is what was created when I added a Calendar from New > App), I can only use the Events web part to display the items in this list. When I try the List web part, my Events List is not an option.

If I set the Date Range option on the Events web part to "This Month", it displays events with a date between today and one month from today. I expected "This Month" to be all events from the current month (based on today's date), so I think this option was worded poorly, but I understand why this choice behaves as it does based on the intended use of the webpart.

If I set the Date Range option on the Events web part to "Select Date Range" and populate the dates I want to use (e.g. for this month it would be 6/1/2021 and 6/30/2021), the web part displays the set of events I expected and would like to see. With the intended and desired outcome determined, the problem now is that I would have to change the To and From dates on the Events web part every month so that the current month's entries are displayed.

With all of this said, I'm left wondering how I can achieve the desired output in an automated fashion. I assume there is not a way to redefine the "This Month" option in the Events web part settings to look at the current month rather than the range of today to one month from today. Is there a way to automatically set the To and From dates in the Date Range on the Events web part every month? Is there another solution for an Events list that will accomplish what I'm looking to do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event web part is the OOB web part in SharePoint Online and we could not change it.

In short, we cannot automatically update the From and To dates in the date range, and must manually change it.

Or you’ll have to look into a custom event spfx webpart, specify this month date range and install it.

Comment: I had a strong feeling that this would be the answer. Thank you very much for the quick response!